# Magento1 TTFB Problem

Tags: magento-1.9

We developed a new website in Magento 1 and have a **little problem with TTFB (specially in checkout)**. Our host made some **jQuery logs** and he told us that every time you load any page the catalogue is loaded. This is the reason why we have enormous load times without the lesti cache. I attached you the log. How can we fix this?

link for query log:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn5ww0pxundde99/20171018-query.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer but I just managed to cut 2 seconds off my Magento 1.9x TTFB by removing the following in `header.phtml`:

```
$this->getChildHtml('topMenu');
```

and replacing it with a HTML version of the menu. It turns out that Magento wasn't correctly caching the menu items and was running huge queries every single page load to create the menu. You'll be able to see if it's your menu causing the problem by adding the following [enabling slow database queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609257/how-do-i-enable-the-mysql-slow-query-log) and monitoring the files results.